# Duolingo home screen is covered by a grey modal background, disabling the page from responding to clicks

Tags: google-chrome, duolingo

I came across this problem on a Mac on Chrome, but I see reports of it on other platforms. I'm self-answering with a workaround here because Duolingo's comments section was too restrictive.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

In short, we're going to find the code that's creating that grey layer and delete it. You don't need to be tech savvy.

1. Right-click on one of the margins on the page (as close to the edge as possible), then go to "Inspect" (Chrome) or "Inspect Element" (Firefox).

   <sup>In Safari, first you'll have to go to *Preferences > Advanced* and enable *"Show Develop menu in menu bar"*. For other browsers, just Google how to "Inspect." It's a pretty universal concept these days.</sup>
2. This should open up a scary-looking panel. Here, we need to find the code, specifically what's called a "<div> block," causing the problem. Your panel may look very different than mine, which looks like this:

   [image]

   You may have to "navigate" a bit to find the line I've highlighted. You can click the tiny arrows pointing right and down to do this. Here's what you're looking for.

   ```
   <body>
       <noscript>...</noscript>
       <noscript>...</noscript>
       <div id="root" onClick>
           <div>
               <div>...</div>
               <div class="_1yGfG _160QG"> <-- Might be different codes for you.
                 ::before <-- Almost there! Keep going...
                   <div>
                       <div class="_16E8f _18rH6 _39TEz _3wo9p"></div> <-- This is the bad one.
   ```

   I'm betting right now it's _16E8f for everyone, but I'm not sure. One hint you've found the right one is when you hover your mouse over that line, the whole page should highlight.
3. Select the line (click on it) and hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>. The grey layer should have disappeared.

#### Note to Duolingo developers:

I think it's happening because of a tracking pixel failing to load in a modal. Here's the console error I'm seeing:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://t.myvisualiq.net/impression_pixel?r=3422676887&et=i&ago=212&ao=546&aca=24380054&si=1781800&ci=135195264&pi=276804369&ad=472248560&advt=4468394&chnl=-7&vndr=115&sz=6586&u=pt=i' because its MIME type ('image/gif') is not executable.
```

An easier solution than trying to debug this problem might be to just allowing modals to close when a user clicks anywhere in the grey region, which is the expected behavior these days anyway.